# dynamically import JS library?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement native lazy loading as per this [article](https://web.dev/native-lazy-loading/) on web.dev. It mainly works as expected in browsers that support lazy loading.

However, I'm struggling with getting the `else` bit working. I'm testing this in FireFox 73.0.1, which I know doesn't support lazy loading. The `console.log` triggers, but the `lazysizes.min.js` isn't added to the `DOM`

Any ideas why? After the page loads, I view source and search for `lazysizes.min.js` it's only present in the `else` statement. I would expect it to be added to the `DOM`

```
 if ('loading' in HTMLImageElement.prototype) {
    console.log('This browser supports lazy loading');
    const images = document.querySelectorAll('img[loading="lazy"]');
    images.forEach(img => {
        img.src = img.dataset.src;
    });
} else {
    console.log('This browser does NOT support lazy loading');
    // Dynamically import the LazySizes library
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.async = true;
    script.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lazysizes/5.1.2/lazysizes.min.js';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Try `document.head.appendChild` over `document.body.appendChild`

Comment: "View source" command shows you the page originally loaded from your server. Use DevTools Inspector tab to see the changes, and Network tab to detect the script was really loaded.

Comment: How are you looking for it in the DOM? `document.body.appendChild(script); console.log(script);` I am sure it is there

Comment: Thanks, it appears in DevTools.